# How is ABC more computationally efficient than exact Bayesian Computation for parameter estimation in dynamical systems (ODE) models?

Tags: bayesian, modeling, markov-chain-montecarlo, approximate-bayesian-computation, approximate-inference

Approximate Bayesian Computation has been suggested as an approach to parameter estimation for computationally intensive simulations, most commonly in population genetics, but also in dynamical systems, for example, [Toni 2009](http://rsif.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/6/31/187) and applied in the corresponding [abc-sysbio tool pubished in nat methods](http://www.nature.com.proxy1.athensams.net/nprot/journal/v9/n2/full/nprot.2014.025.html).

In a dynamical systems model, the likelihood is expensive to calculate because it requires running a simulation to evaluate the likelihood. However, unlike stochastic population genetics model, one could reasonably obtain a likelihood from a dynamical systems model by imagining a probabilistic representation of the RMSE (e.g. treating errors as normally distributed) and obtain a likelihood from a *single* simulation.

So in both exact and approximate bayesian computation, each likelihood calculation entails running a single ODE simulation, how is it that ABC is computationally advantageous as compared to exact bayesian computation approaches? Where does the speedup come from?

Comment: If you can compute the likelihood function at the same cost as for the ABC computation, there is no debate as to which method to use: go for the exact Bayesian solution.

Comment: do you have any comments on the Toni paper? Maybe I'm not understanding something, but the distance functions require ODE integration and it seems to me there's not much of a computational savings in using SSE relative to explicitly evaluating the actual likelihood using a gaussian noise model. Why not apply SMC using the full likelihood?

Comment: Related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283113/in-what-situations-would-one-use-approximate-bayesian-computation-instead-of-bay/283164#283164

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is similar to HMC in that it uses a type of stochastic gradient instead of a random walk. I didn't see anywhere that they say they could do the estimate based on a single simulation. Instead, it looks like you can simply get good values much faster. It really looks very similar to HMC as it's implemented in Stan. I would actually recommend Stan, since it looks like it has better documentation and there are some books on it currently.

Comment: i tried stan and i'm generally a fan when it comes to hierarchical models.

maybe i did something wrong, but it managed to freeze up trying to solve a single first order equation for an exponential decay.

i think the sequential monte carlo aspect of the paper is interesting. i just don't understand the use of ABC when you need to solve the ODE in order to compute the summary statistic.

Comment: Stan is capable of handling differential equation models, though I believe it can be tricky to implement them.  You might consider looking around or asking questions on the stan-users mailing list; a lot of the developers hang around there and are often happy to provide answers or support. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/stan-users