# In what situations would one use Approximate Bayesian Computation instead of Bayesian inference?

Tags: bayesian, inference, likelihood, approximate-bayesian-computation

I'm not sure why one would use ABC/Likelihood-free inference methods instead of standard Bayesian inference methods. Is this fundamentally a conceptual problem of mine?

Are there any concrete examples which could elaborate on when to use the former as opposed to straightforward Bayesian inference?

Comment: see also http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1461-0248.2011.01640.x/abstract

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the great [Wikipedia article on ABC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation) (emphasis added):

> Approximate Bayesian computation (ABC) constitutes a class of
>   computational methods rooted in Bayesian statistics. In all
>   model-based statistical inference, the likelihood function is of
>   central importance, since it expresses the probability of the observed
>   data under a particular statistical model, and thus quantifies the
>   support data lend to particular values of parameters and to choices
>   among different models. For simple models, an analytical formula for
>   the likelihood function can typically be derived. However, **for more
>   complex models, an analytical formula might be elusive or the
>   likelihood function might be computationally very costly to evaluate.**
>
> **ABC methods bypass the evaluation of the likelihood function.** (...)

When using ABC we [*approximate* the likelihood function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90276/abc-how-can-it-avoid-the-likelihood-function) using some kind of summary statistics, so you rather would not use it instead of non-approximate Bayesian computation. We can use it in situations, where we cannot use the non-approximate methods.

Check the famous [socks example by Rasmus Bååth](http://www.sumsar.net/blog/2014/10/tiny-data-and-the-socks-of-karl-broman/) for some friendly introduction (see also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265271/approximate-bayesian-computation-where-to-start-from/265311#265311)).